# loading images from disk in iPhone app is slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my iPhone app, I am using the iPhone's camera to take a photo and save it do disk (the application's documents folder). This is how i save it:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoTaken, 0.0) writeToFile:jpegPath atomically:YES];
```

Using the most compression, I figured reading the image from disk would be quick. But its not! I use the image as the background image for a button in one of my views. I load it like this:

```
[self.frontButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:frontPath] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I navigate to the view with this button, it is slow and choppy. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`+imageWithContentsOfFile:` is synchronous, so the UI on your main thread is being blocked by the image loading from disk operation and causing the choppiness. The solution is to use a method that loads the file asynchronously from disk. You could also do this in a background thread. This can be done easily by wrapping the `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` in `dispatch_async()`, then a nested `dispatch_async()` on the main queue that wraps `-setBackgroundImage:` since UIKit methods need to be run on the main thread. If you want the image to appear immediately after the view loads, you'll need to pre-cache the image from disk so it's in-memory immediately when the view appears.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:frontPath];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.frontButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });

});
```

As an aside, if the button image happens a gradient, consider using the following properties to ensure the image file loaded from disk is tiny:

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
```

or (deprecated, only use if you need to support iOS 4.x):

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

Comment: @Andrew how do you pre-cache? re:"you'll need to pre-cache the image from disk"

Comment: @Van Du Tran, pre-caching in this case means just loading the image into a UIImage before you need it (e.g. before the view appears). This way, when you do load the view, the image is already held in memory so no disk I/O is required to show it on screen.

Comment: It looks like Apple [is warning](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) against using `UIKit` classes on background threads.

Comment: [UIImage is thread-safe](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage). Apple states: **Note**: `Because image objects are immutable, you cannot change their properties after creation. Most image properties are set automatically using metadata in the accompanying image file or image data. The immutable nature of image objects also means that they are safe to create and use from any thread.`

Answer (score 4):

This is the faster way I know. You'll need to import `#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`

I use this code to download and compress images during a scroll, inside a scrollview and you barely notice the delay.

```
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)mutableData, NULL);
CFDictionaryRef options = (CFDictionaryRef)[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform, (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent, (id)[NSNumber numberWithDouble:200.0], (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize, nil];
CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, options);

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnail];
// Cache
NSString *fileName = @"fileName.jpg";
NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"thumbnail"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) {
    // Success
}
```

Comment: If this code still slow for you, you just need to put it inside a thread. Please note that "200.0" is the maximum size that you want in pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I face a very similar issue where I had to load hundreds of images from the directory. My performance was quite slow if I used UIImage(contentsOfFile:)   method. The below method increased my performance to 70 %.

class ImageThumbnailGenerator: ThumbnailGenerator {
       private let url: URL

```
    init(url: URL) {
       self.url = url
    }

func generate(size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as NSURL, nil) else {
        return nil
    }

    let options: [NSString: Any] = [
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: Double(max(size.width, size.height) * UIScreen.main.scale),
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true
    ]

    return CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options as NSDictionary).flatMap { UIImage(cgImage: $0) }
 }
}
```